# Eclipse not recognizing Maven dependent Springframework JAR files

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

I am trying to compile a java program, can see build is completing successfully. But if i open java program can see errors in java springframework dependence package imports. Though having those jars in the lib folder, getting the error.

Tried following commands,

```
mvn clean install
mvn package -P local -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

It is building the jar.

But not resolving the jar issues. Then i tried giving.

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

Getting below error messages. I can see the dependent jars again in the paths mentioned in the error but still facing the issue.

Any pointers will be highly helpful.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.1
0:eclipse (default-cli) on project fileloader: Execution default-cli of goal org
.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.10:eclipse failed: A required class
 was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.10:
eclipse: org/codehaus/plexus/resource/loader/ResourceNotFoundException
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.10
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/xxxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/
maven-eclipse-plugin/2.10/maven-eclipse-plugin-2.10.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/xxxxxx/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexu
s-interpolation/1.11/plexus-interpolation-1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/xxxxxx/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3
.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/xxxxxx/.m2/repository/backport-util-concurrent/
backport-util-concurrent/3.1/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/xxxxxx/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-jdk14/1.5
.6/slf4j-jdk14-1.5.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/xxxxxx/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/
1.5.6/jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/xxxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reportin
g/maven-reporting-api/2.2.1/maven-reporting-api-2.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/xxxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/do
xia-sink-api/1.1/doxia-sink-api-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/xxxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/do
xia-logging-api/1.1/doxia-logging-api-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/xxxxxx/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1
.2/commons-cli-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/xxxxxx/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plex
us-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-4/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/xxxxxx/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plex
us-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/xxxxxx/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plex
us-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/xxxxxx/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.
2/commons-io-2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/xxxxxx/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plex
us-archiver/2.6.3/plexus-archiver-2.6.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/xxxxxx/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plex
us-io/2.1.3/plexus-io-2.1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/xxxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commo
ns-compress/1.8.1/commons-compress-1.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/xxxxxx/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plex
us-utils/3.0.20/plexus-utils-3.0.20.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/xxxxxx/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plex
us-interactivity-jline/1.0-alpha-5/plexus-interactivity-jline-1.0-alpha-5.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/xxxxxx/.m2/repository/jline/jline/0.9.1/jline-
0.9.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/xxxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-a
rchiver/2.5/maven-archiver-2.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/C:/Users/xxxxxx/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plex
us-resources/1.0-alpha-7/plexus-resources-1.0-alpha-7.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/C:/Users/xxxxxx/.m2/repository/biz/aQute/bndlib/0.0.145
/bndlib-0.0.145.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/C:/Users/xxxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/
maven-osgi/0.2.0/maven-osgi-0.2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/C:/Users/xxxxxx/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/core/resourc
es/3.3.0-v20070604/resources-3.3.0-v20070604.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.codehaus.plex
us.resource.loader.ResourceNotFoundException
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContaine
rException
```

Comment: Which lib folder? You are using maven, which means you should use maven to manage your dependencies NOT in some local `lib` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that some artifacts related to eclipse maven plugin are currupted in local maven repo.

So,

1. Delete the entire .m2 folder. (You can also try deleting just org folder in .m2 first to see if it works)
2. Fire mvn clean install -U
3. Fire mvn eclipse:eclipse

Btw, rather than firing eclipse:eclipse you can directly import a maven project in eclipse through File -> Import -> Existing Maven projects.